Laravel migration default
**I'm following the 4 hour laravel tutorial on youtube and I'm using a windows and he was using Mac,
After doing the part in validation and store listing this happened to my code**
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Listing extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'company', 'location', 'website', 'email', 'description', 'tags'];

    public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
    {
        if($filters['tag'] ?? false) {
            $query->where('tags', 'like', '%' . request('tag') . '%');
    
        }
    
        if($filters['search'] ?? false) {
            $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%')
            ->orWhere('tags', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%');
    
        }
    }
}

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into listings (updated_at, created_at) values (2024-06-24 01:32:17, 2024-06-24 01:32:17))


I'm expecting this to happen. Sorry I'm still a beginner on this one.

aint pro but here's a tips, always check the input and output with debugger like dd(); or log::debug(); look like your input is null and affect the $query to be null

Welcome to SO ... the error is for inserting a record, not querying for a record ... you would have to look at the code involved with inserting to make sure you are providing all the required fields/values

Please share the code using which you're inserting record. It seems your data does not have sufficient fields.
